# PyPI role maintenance - Owners vs. Maintainers

Tags: python, pypi

Am I reading correctly in assuming that only 'Owners' can push new versions, or can 'Maintainers' do so as well?

The Maintainer's role is listed as "Can submit and update info for a particular package name.".  Specifically what info can a maintainer edit?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the current [*Warehouse* engine](https://github.com/pypa/warehouse) backing PyPI, a Maintainer only [has the *upload* permission](https://github.com/pypa/warehouse/blob/2b63adfeafbed7bd92085e82aa3c70f728da96ae/warehouse/packaging/models.py#L181-L193).

Anything else requires the user to be an owner.

Warehouse is a Pyramid project, so you can read up on how access control is managed in the [Pyramid *Security* documentation](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/security.html); views are protected by [specific permissions](https://sourcegraph.com/search?q=repo:%5Egithub%5C.com/pypa/warehouse%24+file:%5Ewarehouse/+%5Cbpermission%5Cs*%3D%5B%27%22%5D%5B%5E%27%22%5D%2B%5B%27%22%5D+&patternType=regexp) (or [manual `request.has_permission()` checks](https://sourcegraph.com/search?q=repo:%5Egithub%5C.com/pypa/warehouse%24+file:%5Ewarehouse/+%5Cbrequest.has_permission%5C%28.*%2C+.*%5C%29+lang:python+&patternType=regexp), and most project views require the [`manage:project` permission](https://sourcegraph.com/search?q=repo:%5Egithub%5C.com/pypa/warehouse%24+file:%5Ewarehouse/+%5Cbpermission%5Cs*%3D%5B%27%22%5Dmanage:project%5B%27%22%5D+&patternType=regexp), which is only given to project owners.

Comment: This was the case with older version of Pypi... not with current Pypi version... see GH issue https://github.com/pypa/warehouse/issues/6217

Comment: @scls: yes, PyPI switched implementations entirely in the intervening 7 years. I've updated the answer to reflect the current situation (with details on how to check for what access control applies to what actions).